# fatsort for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fat32, sorting

I've used a program in Linux called fatsort to reorder the directories on my USB flash drive so that my car stereo navigates folders in alphabetical order instead of random order.  Is there any equivalent that works in Windows 7?

http://fatsort.sourceforge.net

Comment: The developer of fatsort says there is a windows version coming in the near future, but I suppose you need it now.

http://fatsort.berlios.de/

Or boot from a linux CD and use Fatsort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried those two following programms on Win7 but at least at WinXP they work.

[DriveSort](http://www.anerty.net/software/file/DriveSort.php)

[FAT Sorter](http://www.fenux.net/story/fatsorteroneohfour)

Comment: DriveSort works fine in Windows 7.

Comment: FAT sorter also works fine on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Fatsort does not work for Windows:

> From: fatsort@formenos.de
> Subject: Re: Fatsort Windows
>
> I thought about porting fatsort for Windows some time ago. Finally, I decided
> that I don't want to support it since file system handling is different in
> Windows and I don't want to perform testing for Linux, Unix AND Windows for
> every release. Fatsort was written for Linux.
>
> I would have to look into Windows API before I could say what needs to be
> changed in the source code. You would definitely have to implement a separate
> file system read write operation for Windows.

However the program [Rosso](//svnpenn.github.io/rosso) works with Windows, and can sort FAT32 drives:

```
rosso F:
```

Answer (score 1):

As the developer, I would recommend YAFS (http://www.luisrios.eti.br/public/en_us/projects/yafs/). It runs on Windows XP/Vista/7/8, Linux and Mac OS X. Unfortunately, there is no GUI for it.